# Очередь выполнения событий JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой вопрос, данный код почему-то сразу убирает обработчик событий, хоть по идее перед этим должен один раз сработать и вывести результат в консоль. Почему так?

Comment: С какой стати он это должен?

Comment: Код не будет ждать, когда вы там кликнете. Запустили, сработало, закончилось. Добавляется обработчик клика, затем сразу же удаляется при выполнении следующей строчки. Когда позже кликаете на кнопку, уже никаких обработчиков у неё нет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> перед этим должен один раз сработать и вывести результат в консоль

Это из каких соображений? Прежде чем удалять обработчик, следует дождаться этого самого клика.

```
const deleteElement = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
  btn.removeEventListener('click', deleteElement);
};

btn.addEventListener('click', deleteElement);
```

Comment: до меня всё равно не доходит, почему конкретно в том коде который я приложил, не выводиться результат в консоль. ведь один раз это должно быть, потому что только потом снимается обработчик

Comment: @hormanfurman Нет, в Вашем коде обработчик снимается сразу же, не дожидаясь клика.

Comment: это я понял, но почему так?

Comment: @hormanfurman Вы понимаете, что событие `click` не может произойти между Вашими двумя строчками `addEventListener` / `removeEventListener`?

Comment: почему не может?

Comment: @hormanfurman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi4_uV5O05I

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы добавляете обработчик события и после сразу же его удаляете.
Я думаю вам нужно ещё раз посмотреть как работают eventListener'ы. Вкратце, первым параметром задаётся событие, которое нужно слушать, а вторым хэндлер (функцию ручку), которая будет выполняться при событии. Т.е. в вашем примере функция сработала если бы вы сделали событие "click", перед удалением обработчика с элемента.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", deleteElement);
btn.click();
btn.removeEventListener("click", deleteElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

А ещё если позволяет поддержка браузеров, то можно сделать так:

```js
function onClick(e) {
  console.log(e.target.outerHTML)
}

var btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.addEventListener('click', onClick, { once: true })
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного промисов:

```js
function onClick(e) {
  console.log(e.target.outerHTML)
}

var btn = document.querySelector('button')

void async function () {
  btn.removeEventListener('click', await new Promise(resolve => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function handler(event) {
      onClick(event)
      resolve(handler)
    })
  }))
  
  console.log('Done')
}()
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

```js
function onClick(e) {
  console.log(e.target.outerHTML)
}

var btn = document.querySelector('button')

void async function () {
  onClick(await new Promise(resolve => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function handler(event) {
      btn.removeEventListener('click', handler)
      resolve(event)
    })
  }))
  
  console.log('Done')
}()
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```